# How to fully match a dereferenced pointer with CIL module?

Tags: c, ocaml, static-analysis

I'm working with
[https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/api/Cil.html](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Enecula/cil/api/Cil.html)

and would like to match the pointers and extract the variable name in a certain expression

> Example (assume this is correct)
>
> int **p0, *p1, **p2, ***p3;
>
> my expression :  **p0 + *p1 + **p2 + **p3

I would like to match the entire dereferenced pointer like : `**p0, **p2, **p3` and not  partially like: `*p0, *p2, *p3` (that's what my code does, thus it will match only `*p1` as desired)

```
class lvalVisitor ctx = object (*f d as params*)
inherit nopCilVisitor
method vlval lval = 

  match lval with
  (*this will match only *pointer and not **pointer or ***pointer *)
  | Mem (Lval (Var v, _)), _ -> printf "derefed. var %s" v.vname
    SkipChildren

  | Mem e, _ ->  DoChildren

  | _ -> DoChildren
  end
```

**TL;DR** I want to tell if a pointer is fully dereferenced or not (counting its stars is not a good option)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question very well, but have you tried using the type (`Cil.typeOf`, or `Cil.typeOfLval`, etc) and traverse the AST until the type is not `TPtr` anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the CIL Api, but would a recursive method not do the job?

For example:

```
class lvalVisitor ctx = object (self)
  inherit nopCilVisitor
  method vlval lval =
  match lval with
  (*this will match only *pointer and not **pointer or ***pointer *)
  | Mem (Lval (Var v, _)), _ ->
     Format.printf "derefed. var %s" v.vname;
     SkipChildren

  | Mem (Lval e), _ -> self#vlval e 

  | _ -> DoChildren
  end;;
```

Comment: Nope, because `e` has type `exp` not `lvalue`

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that we only have dereferences and variables, which the case in your examples, basically you just have to `SkipChildren` after the *first* encountered `Mem`:

```
class lvalVisitor ctx = object(self) (*f d as params*)
  inherit nopCilVisitor
    method vlval lval = 
      match lval with
      | Mem _, _ -> do_something lval; SkipChildren
      | _ -> DoChildren
end
```

This should (not tested) call `do_something` on all topmost dereferences and only them, i.e. from your examples on `**p0`, `*p1`, `**p2` and `**p3`. In a more intricate situation, such as *(*p + o), `do_something` will see the whole lval, and only it. You have not specified what should be done in that case. If you want to examine also `*p`, then `do_something` should in fact be another method, and you should call 
`visitCilLval (self:>cilVisitor)` when you want to restart the recursion to explore deeper.